# Why is there an "expect expression" in my C code on xcode?

Tags: c, xcode

I am trying to make this short program work, but it gives a message of "expect expression" in the following part:

```
        else
        {
            printf("program error!");
        }
```

It looks like I am not using the if-elseif-else correctly. I've searched the web and found that the format is how I have it. Please help.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( )
{
    double height, weight, bmi;
    int bmievalcode;

    while( 1 )
    {
        /* --> add code to input weight and height between here */
        printf("Please enter weight in pounds and height in inches\n");
        scanf("%lf %lf", &weight, &height);
        

        bmi = (weight * 703.0)/(height * height);
        
        bmievalcode = -1;
        
        if (bmi < 18.5)
        {
           bmievalcode = 1;
        }
        else if (bmi >= 18.5 && bmi <25.0)
        {
           bmievalcode = 2;
        }
        else if (bmi >=25.0 && bmi < 30.0)
        {
           bmievalcode = 3;
        }
        else if (bmi >=30.0)
        {
           bmievalcode = 4;
        }



        /*  bmievalcode:
         *  1 = underweight
         *  2 = normal
         *  3 = overweight
         *  4 = obese
         */          

   
        if (bmievalcode == 1 || bmievalcode == 2 || bmievalcode == 3 || bmievalcode == 4)
            printf("bmi = %6.1lf, evaluation is ",bmi);
        {
            if (bmievalcode == 1)
                printf("underweight");
            else if (bmievalcode == 2)
                printf("normal");
            else if (bmievalcode == 3)
                printf("overweight");
            else if (bmievalcode == 4)
                printf("obese");
            printf(".\n");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("program error!");
        }
        

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you please post the output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is wrong here:

```
        if (bmievalcode == 1 || bmievalcode == 2 || bmievalcode == 3 || bmievalcode == 4)
            printf("bmi = %6.1lf, evaluation is ",bmi);
        {
            if (bmievalcode == 1)
                printf("underweight");
            else if (bmievalcode == 2)
                printf("normal");
            else if (bmievalcode == 3)
                printf("overweight");
            else if (bmievalcode == 4)
                printf("obese");
            printf(".\n");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("program error!");
        }
```

The `{}` block isn't part of the `if`, it's separate. Then you have an `else`, but it's not directly after an `if` statement, which causes the error you see.

Move the line `printf("bmi = %6.1lf, evaluation is ",bmi);` to be after the opening `{`.

---

The statement directly after the `if` is what is affected by the condition. If this could compile, only that first `printf` would be conditionally executed. The curly-brace block would always run.

In this case, GCC is a little more helpful than Clang, telling you `error: 'else' without a previous 'if'`